# Expected the value to be an object but received string instead

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Error:

```
ValidationError > s.object(T)
  Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead

  Received:
  | 'Recon#6749'

    at ObjectValidator.handle (C:\Users\Avtandil Rusishvili\Desktop\rbx\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1202:25)
    at ObjectValidator.parse (C:\Users\Avtandil Rusishvili\Desktop\rbx\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:207:88)
    at EmbedBuilder.setAuthor (C:\Users\Avtandil Rusishvili\Desktop\rbx\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:278:26)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Avtandil Rusishvili\Desktop\rbx\slashCommands\moderation\update.js:87:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Avtandil Rusishvili\Desktop\rbx\events\interactionCreate.js:59:6)
```

Its seems like I Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead
no idea how to solve if. Do you have any ideas how i can solve it?

I am using discord.js v14 and node.js v18.15.0

Code:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, ApplicationCommandType, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');
const noblox = require('noblox.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const dataDir = 'slashCommands/data/';

module.exports = {
  name: 'update',
  description: 'Update roles for a user',
  type: ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  options: [
    {
      name: 'member',
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
      description: 'The member you want to update',
      required: true,
    },
  ],

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const userId = interaction.options.getUser('member').id;
    const guildMember = await interaction.guild.members.cache.get(userId);
    const guild = interaction.guild;

    // Geting guild id
    const guildId = interaction.guild.id;

    // Load the group data and etc
    const groups = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${dataDir}${guildId}.json`, 'utf8'));

    // Load the user data from verifiedUsers.json
    const verifiedUsersPath = `verifiedUsers.json`;
    const verifiedUsers = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${dataDir}${verifiedUsersPath}`, 'utf8'));

  // Search user details by discordId
  const user = verifiedUsers.find(u => u.discordId === userId);
  if (!user) {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle('Error')
      .setDescription('This member has not verified their account')
      .setColor('#ff0015');
    return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false });
  }  

  const robloxUsername = user.robloxUsername;

    if (!robloxUsername) {
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Error')
        .setDescription('This member has not verified their account')
        .setColor('#ff0015');
      return await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false });;
    }
```

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4X6x.png)
[verifiedUsers.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cb70.png)

If you need more information ask
again i using
discord.js v14 and node.js v18.15.0

Comment: You should edit your question and add the full error message.

Comment: Ok i will edit the code

Comment: Zsolt Meszaros done.

Comment: Provide the complete code and error message. The error message should indicate where the errors are coming from by telling you the line and column number.

Comment: Thanks, the error is coming from line 87 in `moderation\update.js`. The code snippet you posted is shorter and doesn't have the part that produces the error.

Comment: In `update.js` you're building an embed and provided a string for `.setAuthor()`. However, it expected an object: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor